# how to keep displaying a border bottom for a link element when a user is active on a page

Tags: css, reactjs, hyperlink, hover

When I click on one link in the navbar I want my border bottom to keep displaying 
There are two behaviours :
- On hover : display the border-bottom.
- When active on the link keep displaying the border-bottom (the user is active on the page).

I don't find how to do this, can someone help me ? thank you !

- File scss -

```css
 a {
    span {
     padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
   }
   a:nth-child(1) :hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid "blue";
   }
   a:nth-child(2) :hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #8e1cfb;
   }
```

- react component navbar tsx file -

```js
      <div>
       <Link to={`${process.env.REACT_STATIC_PUBLIC_PATH}`}>
        <span>Link 1</span>
       </Link>
       {''}
       <Link to={`${process.env.REACT_STATIC_PUBLIC_PATH}`}>
        <span>Link 2</span>
       </Link>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just handle the `active` class in your CSS. For example:

```css
.active {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #2196f3;
}
```

Since you're using react-router `Link`, you'll get an `active` class added by default when the route is active.

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit]**: My solution below works fine but does not use the default 'active' class added by react router itself when you click on a Link. I played with it on [This Stackblitz for react-router](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter?file=index.js) (You will need to update package and change `Link` to `NavLink` if you are using router v5) but couldn't make the active class work properly, the `active` class wasn't removed from the first Link, don't know why (But you can inspect the code and you'll see it **is added to your other links**).

Now, if you want, there is also a `activeStyle` you can use (Not recommanded, bleh).

---

Your links are all first child of a div so you could do :

```
const App = () => {
  const setActiveLink = e => {
    // easier for me, you can change with getElementById or getElementByClassName
    const links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); 

    Array.from(links).forEach(el => el.classList.remove("active"));
    e.target.classList.add("active");
  };

  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <a href="#" onClick={setActiveLink}>
        link 1
      </a>
      <a href="#" onClick={setActiveLink}>
        link 2
      </a>
      <a href="#" onClick={setActiveLink}>
        link 3
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Adn in your css simply add :

```
div > a {

  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

div > a:hover{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Of course you have to adapt the the css tags I chose to match your code. Here the stackblitz for exemple : [Example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mirgvn?file=index.js)